# selecting imageview in listview row android

Tags: android, listview, imageview, contacts

I'm currently working on an application that requires a list of contacts to be shown.
You can click on their name and it would bring you to a new screen showing information about this contact and allowing you to call them by selecting their phone number. However,

I want to add a call-icon (currently ImageView) next to the names in the list and when the user presses the call icon instead of the name, the phone immediately calls that user instead of going to the information page.

I've already added the image to the row and have made it clickable, but I have absolutely no idea how to implement an onClickListener to it. I've done a lot of searching but most tutorials seem to only explain how to add images to a row, but not how to add an OnClickListener to it and have it do something.

Here's the XML for respectively the List and the Row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_notes"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the one for the Row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="26sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/phoneButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_call" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the onListItemClick method:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, PersonalPhonebookView.class);
    i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_VIEW);
}
```

Some of you might recognize pieces of the code from the Android notepad tutorial. That's because I've used the notepad code to create a custom contactslist. I'm not a good programmer so I needed something to start with.

Here's an image of the screen

[image]

What I have is when the user selects one of the names, he goes to the information page of this user. What I want is when the user selects the phone to the right of the contact, the phone automatically calls to the phone number of this user. How can I do this?

Comment: have you implement custom `BaseAdapter` to fill up list?

Comment: No I haven't yet. Do you mean something like this: http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/how-to-use-baseadapter-and-onitemclicklistener-in-android/
As a matter of fact, that link solves my problem! In 7 hours, I'll be able to answer my own question here. Thanks to your question, I've managed to find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Correction, I haven't found the solution yet. The images in the tutorial I've linked are not interactive, so my question still stands :(

Comment: I posted solution to solve your problem.

Comment: Lol first time I have seen a screenshot like that.

Answer (score 0):

Write imageView.setOnClickListener in the getView() method of the adapter while populating each row in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this `getView` method to create `custom BaseAdapter` :

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater viewInflater;
            viewInflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = viewInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (holder.textview != null && position < data_text.length)
            holder.textview.setText(data_text[position]);
        if (holder.imageview != null && position < data_image.length){
            holder.imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);
            holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                 
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Clicked : "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                     
                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
      TextView textview;
      ImageView imageview;
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can add click of that component in **getView** method itself 
here is the small example of it  .

```
.......

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    .................
    .................
    .................
    txt_assassinate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("Adapter k ", " position " + position);
            openpopup();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}


.............
```